# How does submit shipment updates the order status in magento 2 admin panel?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, shipping, order-grid

I am looking for a Controller from where does the Order status gets updated in  sales_order  when we click on Shipment in magento 2 admin panel

[image]I want to hook some event on Submit Shipment button in Sales Order View New Shipment Form.

Answer (score 0):

`Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/events.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- instance"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<events name="sales_order_shipment_save_after">
  <observer name="vendor_shippment" 
  instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Order"/>
</events>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

 namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

 use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

 class Order implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
   public function execute(Observer $observer)
   { 
      $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
      $order = $shipment->getOrder();
      $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
      $shippingDetails = $order->getShippingDescription()
   }
}
```